# Find the principal remainder of $\frac{431^5 + 611}{27}$

Tags: chinese-remainder-theorem

I have this problem: $\frac{431^5 + 611}{27}$
I'm supposed to find the principal remainder by hand. But I have no idea how to start when $431$ has en exponent of $5$. Can someone please explain? Thanks.

Comment: Can you determine $431 \bmod {27}$?  Can you determine $611 \bmod {27}$?

Comment: @RobertShore Is 431 (mod 27) = 26 ? And 611 (mod 27) = 17 ? If it isn't then I don't know.

Comment: @Ridertvis: Your arithmetic is correct.  Now, what is $26^5 \operatorname{mod} 27$?

Comment: Think of it as $431 \equiv -1 \pmod {27}$.  That makes the exponentiation *much* easier.

Comment: @RobertShore Can you explain that further. Please.

Comment: @Dan 26 according to my calculations.

Comment: @Ridertvis: Good.  (And I hope you took a shortcut instead of working out $26^5 = 11881376$ by hand.)  Now, what's $(26 + 17) \operatorname{mod} 27$?

Comment: @Dan If I have understood this correctly then that should be 16.

Comment: @Ridertvis: Yes, it's 16.  And my work here is done.

Comment: The point is that $431 \equiv -1 \pmod{27} \Rightarrow 431^5 \equiv (-1)^5 = -1 \pmod {27}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We write the fraction as $\dfrac{(15\times27+27-1)^{5}+21\times27+44}{27}$

which is equal to $\dfrac{M\times\,27\,-1+44}{27}=M+\dfrac{43}{27}$

and $43=27+16$, hence the remainder is $16$.

I am sorry I have not checked the result with a calculator.

Comment: I don't understand what happens between step 1 and 2. Where does big M come from?

Comment: When we have $(A27-1)^{5}$ by the binomial identity this is a multiple of $27 -1$. So in the nominator we have a multiple of $27$$ -1+44=M27+43$